# Getting an Error in AngularJS Post 404 Bad Request Error

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am brand new to AngularJS and I'm pretty lost.  On submitting a form I'm getting the error message: POST http://prerelease.vidaexpress.com/api/account/token 400 (Bad Request).  The error happens when I try to submit the form.  Maybe someone can help me.  Part of my service is below:

```
    (function () {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('vidaexpress')
        .service('accountService', accountService);

    accountService.$inject = ['$http', '$window', '$rootScope', 'apiUrl'];

    function accountService($http, $window, $rootScope, apiUrl) {
        var baseUrl = apiUrl.account;
        var cookieUser;
        var sessionName = 'userInfo';

        this.logIn = logIn;
        this.logOut = logout;
        this.signUp = signUp;
        this.setUserInfo = setUserInfo;
        this.getUserInfo = getUserInfo;
        this.confirm = confirm;
        this.recoveryPassword = recoveryPassword;
        this.resetPassword = resetPassword;
        this.sendVerifyEmail = sendVerifyEmail;

        function logIn(credential) {
            return $http({
                method: 'POST',
                url: baseUrl + 'token',
                headers:{ 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' },
                transformRequest: function (obj) {
                    var str = [];
                    for (var p in obj)
                        str.push(encodeURIComponent(p) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(obj[p]));
                    return str.join("&");
                },
                data: {
                    grant_type: 'password',
                    email: credential.email,
                    password: credential.password
                }
            }).then(function (response) {
                if (!response) {
                    return { error: 'System Error' };
                } else if (response.error) {
                    return { error: response.error };
                } else {
                    return response.data;

                }
            }, function (error) {
                return { error: 'System Error' };
            });
        }
        function logout() {
            return $http.post(baseUrl + 'logout');
        }
        function signUp(userInfo) {
            return $http.post(baseUrl + 'signup', userInfo);
        }
        function setUserInfo(userInfo) {
            cookieUser = userInfo;
            $rootScope.currentUser = userInfo;
            $window.sessionStorage.setItem(sessionName, JSON.stringify(userInfo));
        }
        function getUserInfo() {
            if (!cookieUser) {
                cookieUser = JSON.parse($window.sessionStorage.getItem(sessionName));
            }
            return cookieUser;
        }
        function confirm(customerId, token) {
            $http.get(baseUrl + 'verifyEmail?id=' + customerId + '&token=' + token);
        }
        function recoveryPassword(email) {
            return $http.get(baseUrl + 'recoveryPassword?email=' + email).then(function (response) {
                return null;
            }, function () {
                return { error: 'System Error.' };
            });
        }
        function resetPassword(model) {
            return $http.post(baseUrl + 'resetPassword', model).then(function () {
                return null;
            }, function(){
                return { error: 'System Error' };
            });
        }
        function sendVerifyEmail() {
            return $http.get(baseUrl + 'sendVerifyEmail').then(function (response) {
                return null;
            }, function () {
                return { error: 'System Error.' };
            });
        }
    }
})();
```

Here is my controller:

```
(function () {
'use strict';

angular
    .module('vidaexpress')
    .controller('accountController', accountController);

accountController.$inject = ['$rootScope', '$state', '$stateParams', 'accountService', 'facebookService', 'toastr'];

function accountController($rootScope, $state, $stateParams, accountService, facebookService, toastr) {
    var vm = this;
    vm.logIn = logIn;
    vm.signUp = signUp;
    vm.signOut = signOut;

    vm.facebookLogin = facebookLogin;
    vm.facebookLogout = facebookLogout;

    vm.recoveryPassword = recoveryPassword;
    vm.resetPassword = resetPassword;
    vm.sendVerifyEmail = sendVerifyEmail;


    function logIn(loginform) {
        vm.signinloading = true;
        accountService.logIn(loginform)
        .then(function (response) {
            if (response && response.error) {
                toastr.error(response.error);
            } else {
                vm.login = {};
                vm.submit = false;
                accountService.setUserInfo(response);
                if (!$rootScope.returncust) {
                    window.sessionStorage.setItem('returncust', true);
                }
                vm.isAccountOpen = false;
            }
        }, function (error) {
            toastr.error(error.error);
        }).finally(function () {
            vm.signinloading = false;                
        });
    }
    function signUp(signupform) {
        vm.signuploading = true;
        accountService.signUp(signupform)
        .then(function (response) {
            if (response && response.error) {
                toastr.error(response.error);
            } else {
                accountService.logIn(signupform).then(function (response) {
                    accountService.setUserInfo(response);
                    $state.go('main.index');
                }, function(error) {
                    toastr.error(error.error);
                });
            }
        },function (error) {
            toastr.error('System Error');
        }).finally(function () {
            vm.signuploading = false;

        });
    }
    function signOut() {
        //Log out Facebook
        var userInfo = accountService.getUserInfo();
        if (userInfo.facebookLogin) {
            facebookLogout();
        }
        //Log out UI
        accountService.setUserInfo(null);
        vm.isAccountOpen = false;
        $state.go('main.index');
    }
    function facebookLogin() {
        facebookService.login().then(function (response) {
            if (response.status == 'connected' && $state.current.name == 'landing.index') {
                $state.go('main.index');
            } else {
                vm.isAccountOpen = false;
            }
        });
    }
    function facebookLogout() {
        facebookService.logout();
    }
    function recoveryPassword(email) {
        accountService.recoveryPassword(email).then(function (response) {
            if (response && response.error) {
                toastr.error(response.error);
            } else {
                toastr.success('An email has been sent.');
            }
        }, function () {
            toastr.error('System Error');
        });
    }
    function resetPassword(model) {
        model.customerId = $stateParams.id;
        model.token = $stateParams.token;
        accountService.resetPassword(model).then(function (response) {
            if (response && response.error) {
                toastr.error(response.error);
            } else {
                toastr.success('Your password has been reset.');
            }
        }, function () {
            toastr.error('System Error');
        });
    }
    function sendVerifyEmail() {
        accountService.sendVerifyEmail().then(function (response) {
            if (response && response.error) {
                toastr.error(response.error);
            } else {
                toastr.success('Email has sent');
            }
        }, function () {
            toastr.error('System Error');
        });
    }
}
})();
```

And here is my view:

```
<form class="form" name="loginform" ng-submit="loginform.$valid && vm.logIn(vm.login)" novalidate>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="email">{{'USERNAME' | translate}} ({{'EMAIL' | translate}})</label>
    <input id="email" name="email" class="form-control" required ng-model="vm.login.email" ng-focus="vm.loginerror = '';" ng-pattern="/^[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z0-9]{2,6}$/">
    <div class="error_msg" ng-show="loginform.email.$error.required && vm.submit">{{ 'EMAIL_ENTER' | translate }}</div>
    <div class="error_msg" ng-show="loginform.email.$error.pattern && vm.submit">{{ 'EMAIL_ERROR_PATTERN' | translate }}</div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="password">{{'PASSWORD' | translate}}</label>
    <input id="password" name="password" type="password" class="form-control" required ng-model="vm.login.password" ng-focus="vm.loginerror = '';">
    <div class="error_msg" ng-show="loginform.password.$error.required && vm.submit">{{ 'PASSWORD_ENTER' | translate }}</div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="error_msg">{{vm.loginerror}}</div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary button_dkblue" ng-click="vm.submit=true;" ng-disabled="vm.signinloading" ve-btn-loading>{{'SIGN_IN' | translate}}</button>
</div>
<span><a ui-sref="password.recovery" ng-click="vm.isAccountOpen=false">{{ 'FORGOT_PASSWORD' | translate }}</a></span>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's error from server side ,status code 404 means "NOT FOUND". The resources are not present which you are request for,so please check your token also it's correct or not

Comment: It was returning the wrong error message.  It was corrected by adding return { error: error.data.error }; to the error function.

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely coming from the URL you are posting to. Can you check the script you are sending this to? 404 isn't a javascript error, but where you are posting it to.

Comment: I'll just post all of my code.  I'm brad new to Angular and JavaScript.  I really don't know what I'm doing.  :)